# Adjective related query

Tags: grammar, adjectives, phrases, parts-of-speech, adjective-phrases

Consider the following sentence:

Anne drank a glass of hot milk.

Here, milk is a noun and hot is an adjective. What is "a glass of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split before the word "of". So, "of hot milk" is a prepositional phrase, which modifies "a glass" to form a noun phrase "a glass of hot milk"

"a" is an article, and "glass" is a noun.

Comment: It's not a modifier. It's a complement. I mean that Preposition Phrase.